# Container controller view sizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I'm currently building a custom view controller container for my iOS project and I nearly understand what I'm doing.  The one thing I'm stuck on is how do you (properly - aka not a hack) add a view controller in PART of the Parent controller's frame.  See how there are multiple view controllers/views in the email app?  How does one build a custom controller container that designates the location of such sub-view controllers?  How do you properly add such a controller?  I'd like to know the "correct" way as designated by apple (best practice).
[image: WWDC Conference Image]

EDIT: After looking at this some more I was thinking a possible way would be to create views with custom sizing and then push those to the parent.  Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sort of answered it yourself. The view you have as an example uses a `UISplitViewController` to show two separate views (left and right). Each of those views has a view controller that owns it. Note that the left side includes all of the view, like the search, nav bar, and toolbar. So just create two separate view controllers and add them to a `UISplitViewController` and you should be golden! The views themselves are created however you normally create views. Storyboards, NIBs, or in code works.

Comment: But see how they're each different sizes? Is that simply solved by creating different sized views in interface builder?

Comment: The widths? Apple doesn't allow you to easily set the widths, so you could either override `layoutSubviews` and do that yourself, or use Matt Gemmell's MGSplitViewController here: https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/

Comment: Yeah I'm building a custom thing and I want to be able to support multiple layouts with individual view controllers...I think I've solved it though. Thanks for the help